# I am not able to post data with php using mySQL query, can some assist?

Tags: php, sql, forms, textarea

At the moment I am having an issue which is not allowing me to insert content from a form on my website to my database. The form has worked before but since adding the tinyMCE editor it throws up the following error when I hit the submit button:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'category='sdcnd j sdjcj', type='sdck sjdc ' ,text='

cdscjdnjc  ' at line 1 (the jibberish input is just for testing purposes)

It seems here that its having trouble inserting into several fields but I can't find anything, would someone be able to point out what is causing this and a probable solution?

See below the insertRecord.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   header("Location: admin_login.php");
}

function valid($id, $url, $heading, $friendlyUrl, $category, $type, $text, $age, $imageName, $location, $error)
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Records</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas"
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><b><font color='Red'>Insert Records </font></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>URL<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Heading<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="heading" value="<?php echo $heading; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Friendly URL<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="friendlyUrl" value="<?php echo $friendlyUrl; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Category<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Type<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Text<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<textarea name="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" ></textarea>
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Age<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Image Name<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="imageName" value="<?php echo $imageName; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="179"><b><font color='#663300'>Location<em>*</em></font></b></td>
<td><label>
<input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr align="Right">
<td colspan="2"><label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert Records">
</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}

include('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$id = $_POST['id'];  
$url = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['url']));
$heading = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['heading']));
$friendlyUrl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['friendlyUrl']));
$category = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['category']));
$type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']));
$text = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']));
$age = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']));
$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['imageName']));
$location = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['location']));

if ($url == '' || $heading == '' || $friendlyUrl == '' || $category == '' || $type == '' || $text == '' || $age == '' || $imageName == '' || $location == '')
{

$error = 'Please enter the details!';

valid($id, $url, $heading, $friendlyUrl, $category, $type, $text, $age, $imageName, $location, $error);
}
else
{

mysql_query("INSERT podContent SET url='$url', heading='$heading' ,friendlyUrl='$friendlyUrl' category='$category', type='$type' ,text='$text' age='$age', imageName='$imageName' ,location='$location'")
or die(mysql_error());

 header("Location: view.php");
}
}
else
{
valid('','','','');
}
?>
```

Any contribution is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Missing a comma:

`friendlyUrl='$friendlyUrl', category='$category'` and

`text='$text', age='$age'`

Comment: None of this is correct because even though it appears to be syntactically accurate, the query will not work with the added comma's.

Comment: It definitely works as I have added new content to the database and I have then displayed that content on a page. The only thing that isn't working is the tinyMCE features/styles in the editor. It simply posts the html into the database in plain text format and outputs it the same way without applying the bold style or italic.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is incorrect.  It should look like:

```
insert into <tablename>
(field1, field2, field3)
values 
(1, 'string ', 'string')
```

Your insert is done like an update statement

```
update <tablename> 
set
field2 = 'string',
field3 = 'string'
where field1 = 1
```